# How do I kill a running Python Script?

Tags: python, kill-process, pywinauto, pyautogui, pynput

I am running a python web scraping script I wrote in a jupyter notebook on a windows 7 system. I am using pyautogui, pywinauto, and pynput. I have the script run 10-40 times but sometimes I need to interupt or kill it. Since the script takes hold of my mouse it is hard to go up to the jupyter notebook to stop it. Any suggestions on what I can do?

I have seen people say press ctrl + c but that isn't working

Thanks!

Comment: try ctr + q to quit the program all together, if that doesnt work I think it might be quit() or exit()! if you just want to go all out you could open up task manager and end the task/process from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `interrupt kernel` option in the menus.
[image]

For the shortcuts, use `Control + 0` to restart the kernel.
`Control + I` is used to interrupt.

The kernel shortcuts are:
[image]